# How to split datetime in oracle into date and time in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, oracle, razor, reporting-services

I am currently doing SSRS and CSHTMML.
In my text query, I have a datetime. How do I split the date and time into two separate user inputs in the UI section?

```
    WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(test.testdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'), 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') >=  TO_DATE ('" & Parameters!testDate.Value & "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you would need two parameters, one for date (`dd/mm/yyyy`) and one for time (`hh:mm:ss`)

```
WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(test.testdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') >=  TO_DATE ('" & Parameters!testDate.Value & "', 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
AND
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(test.testdate, 'HH/MI/SS'), 'HH/MI/SS') >=  TO_DATE ('" & Parameters!testtime.Value & "', 'HH/MI/SS')
```